# Mutex, Windows 10, c++, Obtain on one thread, release on another

Tags: c++, mutex

I know how mutexes on windows normally work. And yes, sure, I could create a test program to find out the results, I'm just wondering if anybody knows before I write this up.

I saw a IDXGIKeyedMutex in the documentation today. It has a weird method of calling it where you can call two methods: Acquire(Key) & Release(Key). Acquire waits to obtain the "mutex" (shared resource) associated with the key, no matter what thread it is on. Release releases the shared resource, no matter what thread it is on. It is expected that NO thread calls to Acquire result in Acquire being called more than once before a corresponding Release is called (for the same key).

In this fashion, a lock-step producer/consumer can be done, like this:
Producer: Acquire(0), write shared resource, Release(1)
Consumer: Acquire(1), read shared resource, Release(0)

That got me to thinking: Can Windows Mutexes be used this way, though it is not documented? What if I create a mutex for two processes and share it out to both of them, and call WaitForSingleObject(m_hMutex,INFINITE) on the one process, and call ReleaseMutex(m_hMutex) in the other process? I'm assuming this doesn't work? Or does it, but nobody uses it this way?

Answer (score 0):

No, this cannot be done for simple reason: **to preserve mutual exclusion**

I think you have misunderstood the `IDXGIKeyedMutex`. 
The documentation of `Release` method simply says:

> Return Value
>
> Returns S_OK if successful.
>
> If the device attempted to release a keyed mutex that is not valid or
>   owned by the device, ReleaseSync returns E_FAIL.

It fails when trying to release a mutex owned by another device and please note here that the mutual exclusion is for **the devices** that share a resource.